# How to share Jupyter Notebook Dashboard?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using the following version of Jupyter Notebook and I have created a dashboard layout.

> The version of the notebook server is 5.0.0

But when I do (File -> Deploy as -> Dashboard on Jupyter Notebook Server), I get the below error message "No dashboard server configured". Please refer the screenshot below. In addition, under 'Deploy as' I do not see → 'Local Dashboard in Jupyter' option. Just wanted to understand what could be the reason for the same?

I wanted to share the dashboard with non-programmers, so what is the other easy way we have to share the dashboard? I have googled this, but the solution which I have got there is almost deprecated. So thought of checking it here. Any help would be appreciated on this.

[Dashboard on Jupyter Notebook Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhiL1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option of deploy as ----> loacal dashbaord is deprecated and has been removed in recent version of jupyter dashbaord bundler. Talking about the NO DASHBOARD SERVER CONFIGURED, You have some error in configuration. take a look at these files once more and configure setup as in 
[these](https://github.com/jupyter-attic/dashboards_setup/tree/master/docker_deploy) files.